# Disable angularjs form submit button if image size is big

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I have a form

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" id="files" file-upload="myFile" ng-disabled="isBig" class="form-control" name="files" />
  <output id="list"></output>
</div>
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="isBig" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ng-click="createUser()">Submit</button>
```

I have a custom directive which binds the file to scope, In this directive, I create the image object and in the onload method check the file size. If the file size is greater than specified limit, I want to unselect the file, disable form submit button and alert the user to select a smaller sized image. I tried setting a scope property in onload method to true if size is greater but it doesnt work.

```
app.directive('fileUpload', ['$parse',
  function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileUpload);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;
        element.bind('change', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            if (element[0].files.length > 1) {
              modelSetter(scope, element[0].files);
            } else {
              modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
              var file = element[0].files[0];
              if (file) {
                var img = new Image();

                img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

                img.onload = function() {
                  var width = img.naturalWidth,
                    height = img.naturalHeight;

                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
                  var isBig = false;

                  if (width <= 200 && height <= 200) {

                    modelSetter(scope, isBig);
                  } else {
                    isBig = true;
                    modelSetter(scope, isBig);
                  }
                };
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Any pointers as to where I am incorrect would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-click will still fire if a button is disabled as it is a click event handler. ng-disabled will stop it submitting a form so get rid of ng-click="createUser()" on the button and put ng-submit="createUser()" on the form.

You could also do it with form validation by having ng-submit="formName.$valid &&  createUser()" and have validation on a form field that makes the form invaid.

The image.onload function will also fire outside of a scope digest so you need another apply wrapping the inside the callback function.

Comment: I changed the ng-click to ng-submit. if convenient can you show me what do you mean by another apply wrapping inside the callback? So if I want to add some property on scope which I can then use in the form field like isBig, is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Adrian's input helped me. I will post the code in case someone needs it. I have added the ng-model to the directive and setting the view value and then render it if image size is according to what we need. add required to form input too.

```
//directive to set uploaded img file to the scope element
    app.directive('fileUpload', ['$parse',
      function ($parse) {
        return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs,ngModel) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileUpload);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){

              scope.$apply(function(){
                if (element[0].files.length > 1) {
                  modelSetter(scope, element[0].files);
                }
                else {
                  modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                  var file = element[0].files[0];
                  if( file ) {
                    var img = new Image();

                    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( file );

                    img.onload = function() {
                      var width = img.naturalWidth,
                      height = img.naturalHeight;

                      window.URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );


                      if( width <=200 && height <=200 ) {

                        ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val());
                        ngModel.$render();
                      }
                      else {
                        //fail
                      }
                    };
                  }
                  else{
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val());
                        ngModel.$render();
                  }
                }
              });
            });

          }
        };
      }
      ])
```

and this is the form input:

```
<form name ="addForm" ng-submit="createUser()" novalidate>

<div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" id="files" ng-model="filename" required file-upload="myFile" class="form-control" name="files" accept="image/*"/>
                            <output id="list"></output>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Submit button. Note that its tied to createUser() function from addCtrl. Also note ng-disabled logic which prevents early submits.  -->
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="addForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```